# UICollectionView not showing cells:

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to use UICollectionView to show the first 10 photos from my facebook profile. However, whenever I run the app, the UICollectionView does not show anything - it remains black and I dont see any cells. (I have set the background colour of the cells to blue and colour of the CollectionView to black, but I dont even see the blue cells)

I am using SDWebImage to load photos onto the cells.

Thank you in advance for any help

Here is my code:

In my header file -

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

@interface LNViewController : UIViewController <FBFriendPickerDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>

@end
```

In my .m file -

```
#import "LNViewController.h"
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *photoCollectionView;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self refreshArray];
    //fetch photos from facebook (this function also has [self.photoCollectionView reloadData] in it;
    [self fetchPhotosMe];
    [self.photoCollectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"photoCell"];
    [self.photoCollectionView reloadData];


}

#pragma Mark UICollectionView

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10;
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath{
    static NSString  *identifier = @"photoCell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //create array with URLs
    NSMutableArray *photosURL = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i <10; i++){
        NSDictionary *photoDic = [self.photosMeArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [photosURL addObject:[photoDic valueForKey:@"src"]];
    }

    //Load Cells
    UIImageView *photoImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    [photoImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[photosURL objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

    return cell;
}
```